# How to prevent water jumping from upper lintel to the lower lintel?

Tags: repair, concrete

Water jumping from upper lintel to lower lintel and water jump to lower window 
[image: View of building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8FCr.jpg)

Comment: This question is very unclear.  I have no idea what you're trying to do, or what you need help with.  Add as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If rainwater is cascading from the upper projecting lintel and causing problems below, I would install a gutter at the upper lintel to catch rainwater and divert it into a downpipe and then into a soakaway or surface-water drain.